# What does it mean an isomorphism of a Dynkin diagram induced by some $w \in W$.

Tags: representation-theory

I read some papers encounter the concept " an isomorphism of a Dynkin diagram induced by some $w \in W$ ". Let's consider the Dynkin diagram 
$$
1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 4.
$$
I found that $\phi(1)=4, \phi(2)=3,\phi(3)=2,\phi(4)=1$ is an isomorphism. My question is: $\phi$ is induced by which $w \in W=S_4$? Are there other isomorphisms of this Dynkin diagram? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for one thing this Dynkin diagram corresponds to $S_5$ not $S_4$. This isomorphism is induced by the longest element in $S_5$, the one that sends 12345 to 54321.  As a group, $S_5$ has 120 automorphisms, all of them inner.  However there are only two (the trivial plus the one you are describing) that preserve the generating set $\{ (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5)\}$ corresponding to the vertices of your Dynkin diagram.

Comment: maybe we can also think it corresponds to $S_4$? The vertices of the Dynkin diagram corresponds to the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\phi$ corresponds to $(1,2,3,4) \mapsto (4,3,2,1)$.